# How to access NSUserdefault data in multiple view controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm using multiple uiviewControllers to store information. I'm using NSUserDefaults to store the data. I have a UIVewController that will total everyting. How do I access the NSUserDefault data and how would I go about totaling it?

Comment: Have you tried this? Are you having a specific problem? There should be no problem using NSUserDefaults from multiple view controllers. Maybe a code sample would help, along with you pointing out the specific issues you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *NSUserDefaults* from any view controller. Just an example below.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int val1 = [[userDefaults valueForKey:@"Value1"] intValue];
int val2 = [[userDefaults valueForKey:@"Value2"] intValue];
int val3 = [[userDefaults valueForKey:@"Value3"] intValue];
int total = val1 + val2 + val3;
```

Comment: Here is an example of some code to store the textfield data. How would I go about adding multiple data: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { [super viewWillAppear:animated]; [tex setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"storedTextValue43"]];

Comment: Sorry. Your question is not clear. Can you explain it little more? You want to add multiple data to user defaults or you want to get multiple values from user defaults and show it in text field?

Comment: Ok here is what I have. 3 UIViewControllers that store user data(numbers 1-100) within UITextfields. I have all the NSUserDefaults setup. I would like to do is have a Totals UIViewController that totals all 3 UIViewControllers. The above code is what I'm using to store the users data.